# How to add Gif Image as a background for QListWidget..?

Tags: animated-gif, qlistwidget

I was trying to add Gif Image as an background for the QListWidget, below is the code that i am trying to achieve it.

```
myMovie = new QMovie(":/images/icon_gif.gif");
movieLabel = new QLabel(this);
movieLabel->setMovie(myMovie);
myMovie->start();

listWidget = new QListWidget(this);
listWidget->setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
listWidget->resize(800,600);

QListWidgetItem *sample = new QListWidgetItem();
sample->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/shutdown.png"));
sample->setText("Sample");
sample->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);

listWidget->addItem(sample);
listWidget->setItemWidget(sample,movieLabel);
```

I want the Gif image to be displayed as background for QListWidget and i want it's animation to be played using QMovie.

[Here is the OutPut image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgsul.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
myMovie = new QMovie(":/images/icon_gif.gif");
movieLabel = new QLabel(this);
ui->label->setMovie(myMovie);
myMovie->start();

QPixmap pix = QPixmap::grabWidget(ui->label,20,30,741,481);
pix.fill(Qt::transparent);
QPalette p;
p.setBrush(QPalette::Base,pix);
p.base();
```

I tried this it worked for me..!